# Ngnix and forwarding requests to a port

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node application running at mydomain.com:1234. It's working and loads just fine. However, when I try to use nginx to forward 80, my connection is refused. My setting is sites-available looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

   location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the content of your file is okay, but you need to place it in `conf.d`. I always call my files there `<domain-name>.conf` but I think the name doesn't really matter. And don't forget to `nginx reload` after changing the file.

Comment: Do I still need conf.d if I have added the symlink in sites-enabled? I was under the impression I  needed one or the other but not both.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think symlinks should also work. In my files I use `$host` instead of `$http_host`. Like this: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: So that didn't do it either. Thank you for your help, but the answer (posted below) was that I had done something boneheaded that was hard to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't something that could easily be seen from this question. If you create your symlink with from inside the nginx directory and use

```
ln -s sites-available/mysite sites-enabled/mysite
```

Everything will look ok. However, since you used a relative path, the link is all messed up and won't ever load your config. Instead you just have to use

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite
```

and then everything works like gangbusters.